# The method getConnection() is undefined for the type request

Tags: java, request

Here’s a line of the code I am using for `Jetty IPAccessHandler` but I am getting error

> HttpConnection connection = baseRequest.getConnection();

Do I need to import a specific library for it?

Comment: Could you please provide error stack trace?

Comment: @Yaroslav Its a syntax error that eclipse is showing.

Comment: Not a syntax error, actually. You need to include the actual code and the type you're trying to call `getConnection()` on--the baseRequest in an IPAccessHandler doesn't *have* a `getConnection()`, which is pretty much why you cannot call it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting this error because the method `getConnection()` is defined for java.sql.DriverManager

[Example](https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/?class=java.sql.DriverManager&method=getConnection)

And not for HttpConnection like you are trying to use.

I think you mean the method `getCurrentConnection()`

Use it like so:

```
HttpConnection connection = HttpConnection.getCurrentConnection();
```

[Example](https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?api=org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection)